# How to specify environment variables for Gradle task in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, environment-variables

I have a simple Java application using Gradle as the build tool. Normally when I run my application using gralde I set a specific environment variable `set MYVAR=myval` and later my application uses this value. When I set up a configuration to Run/Debug my Gradle based application in IntelliJ all goes well except that I have no way that I can find to specify my environment variable MYVAR and thus it is always unset.

I've been reading up on my options in various documents and articles for over two hours now and have gotten nowhere.